# How to check recref.field(Integer) is empty or exists in Navision Development ( C/ALL )?

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

`RecRef` is datatype of `RecRef`, and by this i access to table and can select the field of the table;

```
RecRef.OPEN(IDTABLE);
RecRef.field(2); // RETURN THE FIELD DATA OF THE IDTABLE.
```

but if this is empty navision send error so;

How to check if `RecRef.field(Integer)` is empty or exists in Navision Development (**C/ALL**)?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use virtual table Field to check which field numbers exist in a table, as well as their data types and other properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301354(v=nav.90).aspx

You may also reference fields using RecRef.FIELDINDEX(i), where i is between 1 and RecRef.FIELDCOUNT. By this you do not need to guess field numbers if you do not know them.

I would also advise to look at Codeunits `423 Change Log Management` and `8617 Config. Validate Management` for advanced examples and scenarios of working with RecordRefs and FieldRefs.

Comment: Thanks, but after search on the codeUnits i don't find how to detect if the field is empty ( In Navision Dynamics Nav this field haven't info). Because after send if the RecRef.FIELD(lCounter).Type is text, integer... etc the navision send error and say the field is empty :)

Comment: You can use IF RecRef.FIELDEXIST(i) THEN ... to check if the field with the specified number exists. If the field exists but is empty, then you can perfectly use RecRef.FIELD(i)

Comment: Thanks Sergeyol, is what i needed.. One thing more is ¿ how you know the question ? i am new at Navision development and is hard to find this things what are so easy in other program languajes.